# How to have multiple graphs generated by one gplot procedure output to a single PDF file?

Tags: sas

The following GPLOT procedure generates many graphs(It gives sales by different product). Say if my product has 'Sofa', 'bed', 'Chairs', it will give 3 graphs, one for sofa, one for chairs, one for bed.

I'd like to have all the three graphs generated to be output to one single PDF  file. I tried the following, but it only keep the last graph generated. Any ideas how I can do this?

```
ODS PDF FILE= 'OUTPUT.PDF';    
PROC GPLOT data = AB.TEMP;     
plot sales*Months=Product;
by Region;
run;
ODS PDF CLOSE;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandwich your code between ODS PDF and ODS PDF CLOSE statements.

```
ODS PDF FILE='my_file.pdf' style=meadow;

PROC GPLOT data = AB.TEMP; 
plot sales*Months=Product;
by Region;
run;

ODS PDF CLOSE;
```

Does this work for you? If so, then you have something wrong in your code. Post your code and log in that case.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.cars out=cars;
by origin;
run;

ods pdf file="C:\_localdata\temp.pdf" style=meadow;

proc gplot data=cars;
plot mpg_city*msrp=make;
by origin;
run;

ods pdf close;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have 10 graphs generated from this one gplot procedure. This method only keeps the last graph. I'd like to have all the 10 graphs to be generated to a single PDF file.

Comment: This works to me the way you want, @lisa.  You may want to update your post to show how it doesn't.